# Retrieve an existing instance in Python

Tags: python, arcgis

I want to call an existing instance from another class in to other class in Python but I don't know how to do this, help!

```
class ButtonSelectRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):        

        cbr = ButtontRetire()
        cbr.off()     

class ButtontRetire(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        pass

    def on (self):
        self.enabled = True

    def off (self):
        self.enabled = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can pass an instance of `ButtonRetire` to the constructor of `ButtonSelectRetire`:

```
class ButtonSelectRetire(object):

  def __init__(self, button_retire):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
    self.button_retire = button_retire

  def onClick(self):        
    self.button_retire.off()


>>> buttonRetire = ButtonRetire()
>>> buttonSelectRetire = ButtonSelectRetire(buttonRetire)
```

In fact, as far as I understand, you want to connect the signal `buttonSelectRetire.onClick` to the callback `buttonRetire.off()` ?

If you are in a PyQt4 program, this can be easily done:

```
self.buttonSelectRetire.onClick.connect(self.buttonRetire.off)
```

Comment: Thank you again Frodon! I tried but it is giving me an unbound error,

Comment: in onClick
    self.ButtontRetire.onf()
TypeError: unbound method onf() must be called with ButtontRetire instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to create the instances. Is it how you did ?

Comment: You're passing the *class*; you need to create an instance of it.

Comment: Thank you Frodon and katrialex, this is what I did

Comment: class ButtonSelectRetire(object):
    

    def __init__(self, ButtonRetire):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
        self.buttonRetire = ButtonRetire             

    def onClick(self):       
        self.ButtontRetire.onf()    
        

class ButtonRetire(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = False
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pass

    def onf (self):
        self.enabled = True
        

    def offf (self):
        self.enabled = False

Comment: Don't hesitate to upvote if the answer was useful.

Comment: Thank you all, I will play with the code for a little bit